# goodness of fit in (prospective) relative risk regression

Tags: regression, risk

Instead of logistic regression when there is a prospectively follow cohort experiencing events there are methods to estimate a relative risk = RR (rather than an odds ratio)
eg http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/159/7/702.full.pdf+html
usually binary regression with a log link or a poisson regression
this is imprtant as OR != RR when the event isn't rare and being prospective we know the prevalence so can estimate a proper RR.
I wondered 1) whether there are any goodness of fit/residuals for these methods and 2) what the advantages over the COx model are - is it that these RR regression are good when the onset of the event isn't sudden so the actual event time isn't clear (though maybe interval censoring could be used)
many thanks

Comment: Your number 2 sounds to me a bit like what David Freedman's critique of using Cox proportional hazard models in experiments, *Survival Analysis* ([Freedman, 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/000313008x298439)) in the American Statistician. As far as fit IMO I would just estimate the expected number of 0's and 1's in subgroups of interest and compare that to the observed proportion and see if the predictions are reasonable. Poisson regression will assign some probability to outcomes over 1 - which strikes me as problematic in binary data like this.

Comment: many thanks, Andy, the Freedman paper looks interesting.

Comment: the data is binary (ie continuous predictors) rather than binomial so there few patients have exactly the same set of predictors to form subgroups but of course I can still form subgroups based on ranges and perform your method of obs vs pred which seems reasonable, thanks again